# Will Regex work for Voice -Split Based On Widget

Tags: regex, twilio

Twilio Studio does not have a Widget that I would call CONTAINS ANY so I am trying to create a test using the Regex option and in a voice context.  For example, if the phrase could be get the mail or open the mail or open mail, then I could create 3 separate Contains Conditions and route them to the same branch element.  But I would like to just have one Condition that would check for any Contains.

This is not a big problem for just a few possibilities but with many possibilities the Studio Flow Chart gets very messy and there is a lot of adding additional Conditions.

It would be nice to just make the Condition be a Regex condition that "fakes" the missing CONTAINS ANY  condition.

I use regx101 code/syntax creator to develop Regex code and test it. The following code checks out legitimate in rex101 but doesn't work in Twilio studio.

/get the mail|open the mail|open mail/mg

Realizing that syntax is everything. I must be overlooking something very important. Or Regex conditions just will never work with voice.

I have attached a screenshot of the Studio CONDITION that doesn't work.

I have also pasted in the section of JSON code generated by Studio but with different phrases than my example.

I need help in making this work.

"next": "say_play_1",
"event": "match",
"conditions": [
{
"friendly_name": "If value regex /open the flower|get flower/mg",
"arguments": [
"{{widgets.gather_mailbox_answer.SpeechResult}}"
],
"type": "regex",
"value": "/open the flower|get flower/mg"

[image: Condition Box from the Studio Flow in question]

Comment: Wild guess: you should not use the `/` in the begin and end of the regex, also no options after the "closing" `/`. Can you share your regex101 trial?

Comment: sharing the regex 101 info

https://regex101.com/r/mr9MXT/1

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for the Split Based On... widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/split-based-on) says:

> Omit leading and trailing slashes with the Regex Predicate.

Admittedly, it said this right at the bottom of the page, but I've edited it so that this warning now appears next to the definition of the Regex predicate.

So, you should use the regex `.*(get the mail|open the mail|open mail).*` to implement a Contains Any predicate for your options.

This does, of course, drop the options you added. Dropping `g` shouldn't be a problem, since the split widget is looking for a boolean response to the predicate, so as soon as one of your options is found it is true. The `m` might be a bit more difficult. I was testing with text messages rather than voice and when I used multiple lines it didn't match. However, you are working with voice and I don't believe the Gather Input widget will add newlines to the captured speech, so it should also not be a problem.

Comment: As neither `^` nor `$` are part of the regex, I don't see upcoming troubles due to the missing option m

Comment: Thanks for the help and tips!  But I am still not successful.

I replaced the current redex script with   get the mail|open the mail|open mail

Comment: Thanks for the help and tips!  But I am still not successful.

I replaced the current redex script with   get the mail|open the mail|open mail.

No slashes or end parameters.  

@philnash The other  Match conditions using CONTAIN work fine but the Match using Redex still does not work for me  Please jump into the Twilio thread request #9494689 if you can.  You can pick up SID # from that thread.

Comment: Oh, cool use-case! One thing I'd suggest (I can't respond on the ticket) is that you check your flow logs for the speech that was captured to see if it should have matched or if the speech to text engine received something different. As I said, I tested with messaging, so the text was exactly as I wrote and it did work for me.

Comment: Thank you for the dialog, @philnash (not often one gets to chat with the Principal Evangelist!)  

SO, I checked the log at the failed split.  "Input evaluated to 'Get the mail.' from '{{widgets.gather_mailbox_answer.SpeechResult}}'
Transitioning to 'say_play_3' because 'Get the mail.' did not match any expression"

From the split match using the regex option I have, "get the mail|open the mail|open mail"

MORE....

Comment: Hmmmm....  Since the captured speech capitalizes the first letter of a phrase, I changed regex accordingly but I don't think case matters.  The change did not result in a match.

"Input evaluated to 'Get the mail.' from '{{widgets.gather_mailbox_answer.SpeechResult}}'
Transitioning to 'say_play_3' because 'Get the mail.' did not match any expression"

I am stuck as I do not wish to add the bones to this application until I can figure out how to use regex in a split using voice correctly.

Preach to me Principal Evangelist!  =)

Comment: So, with the help of Estela the problem is kinda' solved but not the solution I was seeking..  The voice to text engine used in Twilio Studio adds a  "." to the end of the spoken phrase. So, I just make sure that the regex contains a "." 

BUT, there is always a but) the regex syntax I ended up using actually is a simulation of a MATCH or EQUALS and not a CONTAINS.    More...

Comment: I would like for the SPEECH_RESULT of "I would like to get the mail." to match true with the regex of "get the mail."  But that is not the case.  With CONTAINS, "I would like to get the mail." will evaluate as true with "get the mail" 

I need to get some help to construct a clever regex syntax that truly mimics the CONTAINS functionality.

Comment: Try `.*(get the mail|open mail).*`. That should help match everything before and after the phrases you want.

Comment: Wowzers. Mr . Evangelist!  You are da' man.  This regex syntax works perfectly! 

Well Done!  Now, I can move forward on the project. After, of course , that I report to Estela that I figured it out using my powerful programming skills! =)

Thank you sooo much!!!

Comment: Glad that worked for you! I've edited my answer so that it's accurate now.